# Tomcat Severe listenerStart error

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, listener, web.xml

I am in the process of migrating my webapp to IntelliJ/Maven/Windows from Netbeans/Linux.  The project didn't want to import so I've had to do it manually one file at a time, which was fine because I wanted to switch it to using Maven for dependencies.

I've tried various solutions posted in the forums but this problem seems different and is probably something really basic missing that I am failing to see.

Any suggestions?

Console output:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin\catalina.bat" run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\zclark.POWERCOM\.IntelliJIdea90\system\tomcat\Unnamed_SpecBuilder2b71ab8ed"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin\bootstrap.jar"
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50512', transport: 'socket'
14/04/2011 2:19:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\csvn\bin\;C:\csvn\Python25\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\intellij idea 9.0.1\jre\jre\bin;c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\intellij idea 9.0.1\jre\jre\bin
14/04/2011 2:19:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
14/04/2011 2:19:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 677 ms
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
14/04/2011 2:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/23  config=null
14/04/2011 2:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1632 ms
Connected to server
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/specbuilder-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/specbuilder-service.xml
            /WEB-INF/specbuilder-data.xml
            /WEB-INF/specbuilder-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>specbuilder</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>specbuilder</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.docx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I just managed to squeeze some more information out of the log via adding a logging.properties file to WEB-INF/classes:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
14/04/2011 2:58:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
14/04/2011 2:58:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Update: pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>webApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>webApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you make sure you've added spring as a dependency in your pom.xml? If you dont want the whole framework, and are adding selective dependencies you may want to add spring-web. It'd help if you could paste your pom.xml spring dependencies too.

Refresh the project once you add the dependency so it shows up in your project tree.

Comment: I've put the pom.xml up there.  I have all the spring dependencies I believe I need and they all show up under the External Libraries listing in the project tree.

Comment: Thats strange! Does the spring-context-* jars show up in WEB-INF? If thats there then you may want to replace individual deps with the whole framework and see if that works. If it does, then its a missing dep, if it doesn't, then its the config IMO.

Comment: "Error running webApp [clean]: No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system."  This looks like it could be an issue with IntelliJ and Maven?  I got that when trying to run anything from the Maven Project Lifecycle

Comment: I use eclipse so not so sure about IntelliJ. What about command line? You can build the project command line by mvn clean install -DskipTests, and then run it by doing mvn jetty:run

Comment: Looking in my directories on the file system.  I got to where it is compiling, webApp_war_exploded and in there is nothing but my compiled java and my front end code.  No libraries or anything. Not sure if that is normal

Comment: Its not normal. You should see a WEB-INF/lib with all the jars in it.

Comment: That would tell me that Maven isn't doing anything, and from the previous error, it looks like I should probably install Maven on this computer... thought it was included in the IDE.  Stupid me