# Can not run hello world spring MVC on openshift skeleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, openshift

I want to create a simple web service based on openshift hosting. I made an initial work and got template -- a set of folders. I added spring mvc facet and setup configurations settings. War has been sucessfully deployed but it doesn't open any page and direct access to page returns 404 code

```
[2015-02-19 11:14:59,001] Artifact shop2client:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-02-19 11:14:59,504] Artifact shop2client:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-02-19 11:14:59,504] Artifact shop2client:war: Deploy took 503 milliseconds
```

Spring application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shop2client"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Controller

```
![@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byjlh.png
```

Can clarify why dispatcher servlet doesn't see my controller?

Comment: what happened if you had <mvc:annotation-driven/> in your applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn;t help. The same issue

Comment: does it work on you pc or with your IDE?

Comment: I use idea to develop this project. I tried this with one ide and one computer

Comment: so does it works on your pc before you deploy it? and give the stacktrace error if there is

Comment: Oh, I got what did you mean. I deploy only locally and it doesn't work

Comment: so you have to find the stacktrace and post here

Answer (score 0):

Changer to

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

to

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you but id doesn't help

Comment: i have edited my answer. Please check this should work

Comment: Tnak you. I got an error: [2015-02-19 12:07:03,509] Artifact shop2client:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Feb 19, 2015 12:07:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 19, 2015 12:07:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330537/im-getting-org-apache-catalina-core-standardcontext-startinternal-severe-erro    see this

Comment: Thanks! I copy lib folder inside meta-ing folder and it is works now. Can you briefly describe why I should define ContextLoaderListener and context param explicitly?